# Get global Tint color from Storyboard in Appdelegate class

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

How to get global Tint color from Storyboard in Appdelegate class?
Neither methods do not work:

```
UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = Windows.TintColor;
UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().TintColor;
```

I'm aware of that how to get tint color in controller:

```
var tintColor = View.TintColor;
```

But i just want to use global tint color from Storyboard outside of view controller and don't want set color in code.

Comment: Right, only POSSIBLE duplicate! Answer there is for ViewController, not ApddDelegate.

Comment: If you read through the anwsers and discussions you will see that there is no global tint available in code. The global tint in the storyboard is applied to controllers/views when they are instantiated from the storyboard. You can only get it from a controller

Comment: So, i do all of my global Tinting in Initial root controller ViewDidLoad
`UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = View.TintColor`